# Remove yellow searched css atribute from applied Styles tab

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This is really a silly question, but I am having trouble removing the searched css rule in Chrome Dev Tools.

First I click on the icon below:

[image]

I'm sure in the previous version of Chrome there was a remove icon but I cant seem to find it, please see below:

[image]

How do I remove the yellow CSS rule box? I'm sure I'm missing something simple?

My current chrome version is 45.0.2454.85

Comment: What about using the backspace key in the input box?

Comment: I didn't realize it is a input box! Thanks!!